# Affine varieties, the Brauer group and gerbes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, etale-cohomology

For an affine variety $V$, the Brauer group $Br(V)$ and the cohomological Brauer group $Br'(V)$ (i.e. the torsion subgroup of $H^2_{et}(V,\mathbb{G}_m)$) coincide, by results of various authors including Hoobler, Gabber etc. In fact it is true for affine schemes, but I have a simpler setup, namely I have a smooth *complex* variety.

However, I have been told that in fact $Br'(V) = H^2_{et}(V,\mathbb{G}_m)$ for affine $V$, and I can't seem to find a reference for this fact. This implies that all $\mathbb{G}_m$-gerbes on affine varieties have torsion class in $H^2$, a fact which I find slightly surprising, but which I can't rule out. My dream is that there are non-torsion elements in $H^2$, but I can live with their absence.

What is a reference, if true, for the result that $H^2_{et}(V,\mathbb{G}_m)$ is a torsion group?

EDIT: not that it is a hugely reliable source, but [wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tale_cohomology#Examples_of_.C3.A9tale_cohomology_groups) (without citation):

> If $F$ is a coherent sheaf (or $\mathbb{G}_m$) then the étale cohomology of $F$ is the same as Serre's coherent sheaf cohomology calculated with the Zariski topology (and if $X$ is a complex variety this is the same as the sheaf cohomology calculated with the usual complex topology).

which would indicate that $H^2_{et}(V,\mathbb{G}_m) \simeq H^2(V(\mathbb{C}),\mathcal{O}^\times)$ where the cohomology on the right is sheaf cohomology for the analytic topology on $V(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: It's entirely possible that whoever added that statement to Wikipedia saw the result about $H^1$ with values in $\mathbb{G}_m$, and wrongly extrapolated.

Comment: as for the wikipedia comment -- it's definitely true that cohomology of coherent sheaves is the same for the étale topology and the zariski topology on an arbitrary scheme. The statement in parentheses I don't know (for proper varieties it is GAGA; for non-proper varieties it's probably false -- at least, certainly it's false for $H^0$ of the structure sheaf.)

Comment: I'm completely confident about the results with coherent sheaves and GAGA, just the statement about the multiplicative group is what I was focussing on.

Comment: I think it's relatively rare for $H^2_{et}(V,\mathbb{G}_m)\simeq H^2(V(\mathbb{C}),\mathscr{O}^\times)$ for a smooth complex variety $V$. For instance, this is impossible if $H^2(V,\mathscr{O})\neq 0$, by the exponential sequence. On the other hand, the étale cohomology group is torsion in this case.

Comment: Without the smoothness hypothesis, there are examples where $H^2_{et}(V,\mathbb{G}_m)$ can be non-torsion, even for a complex variety. I guess the earliest example is due to Grothendieck and Mumford. It is a normal surface, which I think is even affine. This is mentioned in Remark 2.8 of Milne's Chapter IV from the book on étale cohomology. By the way, that reference has a lot of very nice facts about the Brauer group. You're original question is answered as Corollary 2.6 there.

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminAntieau, I flicked through Milne's copy on his website, and the book, but didn't see that, just the cases of curves, spectra of Henselian rings and so on.

Comment: Oh, this is his print book "Étale cohomology", which is rather different from "Lectures on étale cohomology".

Comment: Oh, yes, I realised that, and I found I had the book on my shelf from the library, so I skimmed both, but didn't happen across IV.2.6 before you mentioned it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the answer at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/171638, there is a theorem of Grothedieck [1] that implies that any non-singular variety $X$ has all cohomology groups $H^q_{et}(X,\mathbb{G}_m)$ torsion for $q\geq 2$. *Why* this is true is still a bit mysterious, even though I have hints to the proof.

[1] *[Le groupe de Brauer II](http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/item?id=SB_1964-1966__9__287_0)*, Proposition 1.4

Comment: You might look at the Leray spectral sequence for the pushforward of $\mathbb{G}_m$ from the generic point.

Comment: Yes, Grothendieck mentions this in his lead up to proposition 1.4

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not an algebraic geometer, so I'll have to take this one on faith and come back to it when I have the leisure.

Comment: Ah, I see: H^2(X,G_m) injects into H^2(Spec K,G_m,K), and the latter is (I guess) a Galois cohomology group, hence torsion.

Comment: Exactly the point.

Comment: It has been a long time since this post, but one way to see the torsion-ness of $H_{et}^q(X,\mathbb{G}_m)$ is to note that $\mathbb{G}_m$ is the weight one motivic complex. Etale motivic cohomology coincides with the Zariski motivic cohomology rationally. So it suffices to show $H_{Zar}^q(X,\mathbb{G}_m)$ is torsion for $q\geq 2$. But it is well known these groups are zero.

Comment: @user127776 This may be useful to algebraic geometers, but not to me. I certainly didn't know about this so-called well-known fact.